Find all f such $f(x+y-xy)+f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$
find all such f(x) $f: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R,$ $f(x+y-xy)+f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$

Don't re-ask the exact questi9n that was previously you asked. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4991271/find-all-such-fx-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-fxy-xyfxy-fxfy

This question is similar to: find all such f(x) $f: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R,$ $f(x+y-xy)+f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

$P(xy,\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})\rightarrow f(xy+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}-x-y)+f(x+y)=f(xy)+f(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})...1$
$P(\frac{1}{xy},x+y)\rightarrow f(\frac{1}{xy}+x+y-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y})+f(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})=f(\frac{1}{xy})+f(x+y)...2$
$1+2\rightarrow f(xy-x-y+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})+f(\frac{1}{xy}+x+y-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y})=f(\frac{1}{xy})+f(xy)$
let $t=xy, s=x+y$
$f(t+\frac{1-t}{t}s)+f(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1-t}{t}s)=f(t)+f(\frac{1}{t})$
and if $t<0$, x+y can be any real number and that means regardless of t, $\frac{1-t}{t}\times s=A$ can be any real number so it becomes
$ f(t+A)+f(\frac{1}{t}-A)=f(t)+f(\frac{1}{t})$ when $A\in \mathbb R, t<0$.
if we put $A\leftarrow \frac{\frac{1}{t}-t}{2}$, we get$f(t)+f(\frac{1}{t})=2f(\frac{\frac{1}{t}+t}{2})$
and if you put $A\leftarrow\frac{\frac{1}{t}-t}{2}+x,$ we get $f(\frac{\frac{1}{t}+t}{2}+x)+f(\frac{\frac{1}{t}+t}{2}-x)=2f(\frac{\frac{1}{t}+t}{2}),  $ let $ p=\frac{\frac{1}{t}+t}{2}$
if -k=t, $\frac{\frac{1}{t}+t}{2}=-(\frac{\frac{1}{k}+k}{2}),k>0 $ therefore by AM-GM, $p=\frac{\frac{1}{t}+t}{2}\leq -1$
Now let's show for $l>-1$: $f(l-x)+f(l+x)=2f(l)$
We have that $f(x)+f(2p-x)=2f(p)...3$
let $p<-1$ ,
$f(-1+x)+f(-1-x)=2f(-1)$,
If you put -1-x in x of 3,
$f(-1-x)+f(2p-(-1-x))=f(-1-x)+f(2p+1+x)=2f(p)$
$f(2p+1+x)+f(-2-2p-1-x)=2f(-1)=f(2p+1+x)+f(-3-2p-x)=2f(-1)$
$f(-1-x)=2f(-1)-f(-1+x)\rightarrow 2f(-1)-f(-1+x)+f(2p+1+x)=2f(p)$
$ 2f(-1)-f(-1+x)+2f(-1)-f(-3-2p-x)=2f(p)$
$4f(-1)-2f(p)=f(-1+x)+f(-3-2p-x)=f(-2-p+x)+f(-2-p-x)$
And, we know that $p<-1\rightarrow -2-p>1$ And if we let $n=-2-p$: for every $n \in \mathbb R, n>-1:$ $f(n-x)+f(n+x)=2f(n)$ and that means for every real number r, $f(r-x)+f(r+x)=2f(r)\rightarrow f(x)+f(y)=2f(\frac{x+y}{2})$ and we have the jensen's functional equation.
The answer of this question is,
"EVERY FUNCTINON THAT SATISFIES JENSEN'S E.Q."
